# Align table columns under d3 chart columns

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a basic column chart in d3.js. I've been tasked with displaying additional data for each column underneath the chart in a table.

How can I align the table columns under their respective chart columns?

The table is raw HTML here for simplicity. I could [generate the table using d3](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/add-html-table-to-your-d3js-graph.html) if that would be helpful for this question.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pqRX8/1/

Or use this file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10, "%");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [
  {'letter': 'A', 'frequency': '.08167'},
  {'letter': 'B', 'frequency': '.01492'},
  {'letter': 'C', 'frequency': '.02782'},
  {'letter': 'D', 'frequency': '.04253'},
];

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });


function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}

</script>

<table>
  <tr><td>Phonetic</td><td>alpha</td><td>bravo</td><td>charlie</td><td>delta</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Pronunciation</td><td>AL-FAH</td><td>BRAH-VOH</td><td>CHAR-LEE</td><td>DELL-TAH</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is possible to position them under the chart by using some CSS and positioning them absolutely or by carefully tuning the CSS of the table such that the center aligned texts appear inline with the axis. However that is prone to error and hard to maintain. You can try to use the SVG `text` elements inside the graph itself, under the axis, instead of trying to put them in a table outside the visualisation.

Comment: Thanks @musically_ut. I had considered adding the table cells to each bar like labels and offsetting them. But the rangeBand() approach seemed like lower fruit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same `x.rangeBand()` for widths of your table columns as you do for the widths of your bars. Don't forget to add a horizontal padding of 5% (10% total) of it to compensate for `.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);`

Comment: Thanks @Oleg. I got a basic implementation working using x.rangeBand(). I didn't completely understand the horizontal padding, but it's working well enough so far. http://jsfiddle.net/pqRX8/4/